# agile virtual whiteboard software

Tags: web-development

what is the best virtual whiteboard software that I can use while developing a project using agile? This software must include the feature of multiple contributors accessing the board of the same project at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

Use Microsoft Whiteboard

https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/microsoft-365/microsoft-whiteboard/digital-whiteboard-app

It's also present inbuild inside the Microsoft Teams.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [`My Personal Kanban`](https://github.com/greggigon/my-personal-kanban) which includes sync to the cloud if you want multiple people to share the board.